# SQL Server 2008 converts query parameters string value to nvarchar(4000)

Tags: sql-server-2008, sql-execution-plan

I am trying to fetch data using composite primary key. I am sending 2 strings as query parameters, but SQL Server execution plan shows query parameters `@p0 nvarchar(4000)` & `@p1 nvarchar(4000)` and it is using index scan instead of index seek. Why?

How come I see `varchar` size 4000, my column type is `varchar` 30 & 255 respectively?

How to force my execution plan to use index seek?

Thanks

Comment: The SQL Server query optimizer will pick **what is best** for your current query. So maybe in your case here, doing a **scan** is ultimately cheaper and costs less processing time and less memory than doing a seek. A seek isn't always just better! How does your table look like? What columns do you have? What data (how many rows etc.) is stored inside that table? What's the query?

Comment: Please show us your **table structure** and the **query** you're talking about! We can neither read your screen, nor your mind ...